# 2x2 mobile flex grid with top menu bar

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I've been trying - and failing - to get the following grid layout in CSS flexbox (no grid, I need to support older browsers):

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I need a

- Menu bar (dark grey), always on top, always full width and fixed height
- a 2x2 grid (blue and white) that's full width on portrait mode and same aspect ratio on landscape
- the purple container using the rest of the available space. Stacked below on portrait and to the side on landscape.

I know about media queries, and I guess I need one to limit the .grid width, but I don't know how to get the landscape layout with that.

Looks simple enough but I guess I need your help! :(

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  width: 50vw;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  max-height: 50px;
}

.purple {
  background-color: #663353;
}

.purple p {
  padding: 2em;
}

.grid:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: #6798cc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row topbar"></div>
  <div class="row wrap">
    <div class="col grid"></div>
    <div class="col grid"></div>
    <div class="col grid"></div>
    <div class="col grid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col purple">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id ipsam rerum laborum velit obcaecati, eveniet reiciendis, veritatis ipsa ducimus recusandae quidem nesciunt dolor facilis sed neque quod.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh well, I've been trying to do this in Bootstrap for the longest time with limited success - but this is as close as I get without.

Comment: To simplify things, take the header out of the flex container because it doesn't need to be in it and you don't need to set flex direction for container

Comment: You just need to set the width of the grid container and the purple container to 50vw at the media query you want for landscape, what is the actual issue you are having?